# Very large memory management in .NET (Windows) 1-120 GB

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I have a requirement to capture large quantities of streaming data (between 8 and 16 HD RGBD and IR image streams at 30fps). I'm concerned that capturing and writing this data to an NVMe drive might further complicate performance, so I want to explore the option of storing these in RAM. On a system with 128GB of RAM this might give me around 2 minutes of capture time and once done I can further process the images and persist the data to a non volatile storage device. I'll do this as a threaded app in .NET on an 12900K system running on Windows 11. However, I have no idea what's the best approach to handling very large buffers and how .NET handles it. Will I hit some memory limits? Should I be using particular .NET structures to do this - I've read a bit about ArrayPools.

Ideally on startup I'd grab several very large (many GB) blocks of memory and then manage them myself after that point. Can .NET handle this? Will it have problems allocating memory due to potential fragmentation before the application starts? Are there process limits that will prevent me doing any of this? (Edit - seems not)

Comment: OK it seems that on Windows I should at least be OK process wise if IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set (default):
x64: Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 or later: 128 TB

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-limits-for-windows-releases?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: This is without doing a tonne of research, but I believe arrays in .NET are limited to 2gb.  However, this doesn't mean you can't write your own data structure behind the scenes to manage an array of 2gb buffers.  You can implement your own `Stream` that abstracts this away, and makes for a nice interface for later copying this stream to some persistence like a disk or network share.  I don't see a limitation within .NET that would prevent representing your video streams as such.

Comment: If feasible, use fixed length buffers initialized at program start rather than variable length arrays dynamically allocated and disposed when an image is processed. If not feasible, you may need to often trigger garbage collection.

Comment: Have a look at the Pipelines API, to me it seems it will handle multiple big memory blocks for you: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2018/07/pipe-dreams-part-1.html, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipe?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0. I would just run a quick test to see if this can handle like 100GB of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I have no idea what's the best approach to handling very large buffers and how .NET handles it.

A general recommendation is to ensure memory is either freed in gen 0/1, or never at all.

If you just intend to capture 2 minutes of data, write it to disk, and then exit you should be fine to just create buffers as you go, since everything will be freed anyway when the program exits.

If you intend for the program to be long running you should probably use some type of pooling. ArrayPool or MemoryPool are certainly options you could use. But given that you will probably have fixed size buffers, or a few different possible sizes, you could probably also use something like a ConcurrentBag for each buffer size. There are probably many other types of memory pools you could use. I would not expect the memory pool to be the performance bottleneck, regardless of what implementation you pick.

> Ideally on startup I'd grab several very large (many GB) blocks of memory and then manage them myself after that point. Can .NET handle this?

As long as you keep a reference to the array you can do whatever you want with the memory. There are by default a max size for a single array, but if you just allocate an array for each frame you should be fine.

> Will it have problems allocating memory due to potential fragmentation before the application starts?

As long as the memory is immediately available from the OS you should be fine. You should probably leave a few GBs for the OS to use to avoid potential swapping.

That said, a single rgb full HD frame is 6Mb, or 180MB/s, or 2.9GB/s for 16 cameras. A nvme pcie 5 drive currently tops out at 10GB/s, so should be able to handle this. But You probably would want multiple drives, or some suitable RAID system, just to give you better margins. You would still want to keep a buffer of frames in memory, but you should not need to keep the entire recording. You might also need to do something to keep writes sequential. Random writes tend to kill performance fairly quickly.

Compression could possibly also be used, and would significantly reduce bandwidth and storage, at the cost of higher CPU usage, or require some form of hardware compression card. Your requirements strongly hints at some form of custom workstation, so I would assume you are free to specify whatever hardware you need. In general, if you can get the data into the computer you can probably save it. As long as you do not do something odd, like inputting compressed data streams, but save uncompressed data. The bottlenecks tend to be in the network, or image capture cards rather than storage.